# The ruby-on-rails-4 tag does not enable syntax highlighting of Ruby code

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, syntax-highlighting

I have noticed that [ruby-on-rails-4](/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails-4) does not enable Ruby syntax highlighting by default. I had to add [ruby-on-rails](/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails) in order to achieve it.

Is it supposed to be like this? Bug or feature?

Comment: Note that you don't have to rely on tags to activate syntax highlighting for you. You can do it yourself by giving a command to Prettify: see [Syntax Highlighting for Code](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have updated the tag to default to `lang-rb` for syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax highlighting language is associated with the tag, and it can be of three types:

- None (There is not syntax highlighting language associated to that tag.)
- Default (The syntax highlighted language is guessed from the highlighting code.)
- One of the language codes

The default syntax highlighting language is set to none for new tags, as I can see on the site where I am moderator.

> [image: screenhot]

This means the syntax highlighting language needs to be set for new tags. The behavior you see is by design.

Alternatively, you can force a specific syntax highlighting language with `<!-- language: [language code] -->` added before the code. In your case, the HTML comment would be `<!-- language: lang-rb -->`; if then you want to set that for all the code snippets in the post, you can use `<!-- language-all: lang-rb -->`.